# Firestore code is not waiting for response

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm new to React Native, Javascript and Firestore.  The issue is that I'm trying to read a firestore database and wait for the response to display information on the next page before it is rendered.

Here is the controller code:

```
  _signIn = async () => {
    try {
      // Google sign in and connect to Firebase
         ... This code is working as expected
      // Connect to the Firebase Firestore and store the connection
        CesarFirestore.setFirestore(firebase.firestore());
        let cFS = CesarFirestore.getInstance();
        cFS.saveLoginDetails(this.cUser);
     // THIS IS THE CALL TO GET THE STATUS OF THE USER
        await cFS.readAvailability(this.cUser);
        this.setState({loggedIn: true});
      } else {
        ... INVALID login coding works fine 
      }
    } catch (error) {
      ... CATCH coding works fine
      }
    }
  };
```

From the above marked line, the following code is executed:

```
  async readAvailability(cUser) {
    let tuesdayDate = new CesarDate().getTuesday();
    let availableRef = CesarFirestore.getFirestore().collection('available');
    let availableQuery = await availableRef
      .where('tuesdayDate', '==', tuesdayDate)
      .where('userId', '==', cUser.getUserId())
      .get()
      .then(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.empty) {
          console.log('No matching documents.');
          cUser.setTuesdayAvailability('NOT_FOUND');
        }
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          cUser.setTuesdayAvailability(doc.get('status'));
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
  }
```

So the readAvailability(cUser) code should wait for the availableQuery to return results.  The results would be then stored in the cUser class which is available to the rest of the application.

What happens is sometimes the result is available and sometimes the result is null. I thinking this is because `doc` is undefined which I have confirmed via the debugger.

Any help would be great and thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you `await` for a function, it must return a value, or a promise that resolves to a value later on. Since you're instead consuming the promise (in your `then()` handler), there is no way for the interpreter to know what to wait on.

```
  async readAvailability(cUser) {
    let tuesdayDate = new CesarDate().getTuesday();
    let availableRef = CesarFirestore.getFirestore().collection('available');
    let snapshot = await availableRef
      .where('tuesdayDate', '==', tuesdayDate)
      .where('userId', '==', cUser.getUserId())
      .get()
    if (snapshot.empty) {
      console.log('No matching documents.');
      cUser.setTuesdayAvailability('NOT_FOUND');
    }
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      cUser.setTuesdayAvailability(doc.get('status'));
    });
    return true; 
  }
```

I'd usually actually make `readAvailability` return the user it modified, but the above should work too.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and helping me out.